# NetSuite IDE security message missing

Tags: netsuite

When I attempt to log into NetSuite from the NetSuite IDE (eclipse), it asks me to answer one of my security questions. However, the dialog is empty and none of my security answers are working. Anyone else had this problem? It was working fine a few days ago.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix this, I had to create a new eclipse workspace and re-import my projects. For some reason something became corrupted in my original eclipse workspace.

Note: Re-installing eclipse and re-using the existing workspace didn't solve the issue.